# Linux 3D graphic libraries

Tags: linux, graphics, opengl

What libraries can be used for 3D graphics on Linux? Are there big differences for 3D graphics programming between Linux and Windows?

I found about DirectX and OpenGl by searching, but I'm not sure that these are graphic libraries.

Comment: Can you provide some context for your question and clarify what you are looking for because as it stands there are at least 5 questions.

Comment: The question `How much are they?` is not a question and `What are the most important?` is only possible to answer given a context as @Karlson mentioned. What are you going to do with the library and in what environment?

Comment: I think this is on-topic, but it is a ton of questions, and half of them can't really be answered

Answer (score 2):

Depending on language you use.

For C/C++ check following:

- libcal3d
- libcoin
- libcrystalspace
- libg3d
- libirrlicht
- libogre

For java:

- libjava3d-java

For python:

- python-soya
- python-opengl

Have fun. Python-soya is probably simplest to start with.